# Generic find_by_sql with typecasts without model methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to run an arbitrary query against my database. For now I always resort to `find_by_sql` to make sure the results are converted into the proper type. The drawback of this method is that sometimes the Rails models have methods associated. If the fields returned by the `find_by_sql` method are present in the model, the methods of the model are used.

The alternative is to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` or `Model.connection.execute`. Hover the results returned by that method are not properly mapped to ruby objects. For instance `DateTime` objects are returned as strings, not as real ruby objects.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_by_sql` but get real database by calling `[:colum_name]` instead of `.column_name`.

Example:

```
q = Question.find_by_sql('select * from questions limit 1').first

q.title
=> "1"

q[:title] 
=> "How to convert MagicaVoxel to vector?"
```